# svg element with stroke-width renders differently in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox, stroke

There is a difference in rendering svg elements with stroke-width in firefox and chrome.

```
<html>
<body>
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:white;stroke-width:3;stroke:red" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

for example if you consider this code in chrome the real size of `<rect>` is equal 400  while in firefox it's 403px It's adding stroke-width to width attribute.

[image: firefox]

Is there any way for them to behave similarly? something like `box-sizing: border-box` could be nice.

Comment: Be aware that the `stroke` is centered over the edge of the SVG element drawn. Half inside the element's edge and half outside the element's edge. meaning that with a `width: 400` and a `stroke: 3` the actual width will be `1.5 + 400 + 1.5 = 403`   (left edge half stroke + width + right edge half stroke). The same goes for top and bottom, in which case you would get `1.5 + 100 + 1.5 = 103`. I don't know why there's a difference in Chrome/Firefox, but it may be related to the missing `viewbox="0 0 400 100"` attribute. Just thinking out loud, though...

Comment: You are right about the calculations but even using `viewbox` won't solve it and I have no idea why this formula is different in chrome. @RenevanderLende

Comment: The strange part is that there is not much info about this issue. no similar issues or questions that answer it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the actual rendering. Both browsers show the stroke in the same position relative to the bounding box of the `<svg>` element, with  the stroke centered on the geometrical boundary of the element. Both browsers clip the rendering at the bounding box of the `<svg>` element, so that for the top, left and right side only the inner half of the stroke is visible. For both, the size of the `<svg>` element is 400px * 110px.

Only in the return value of `rect.getBoundingClientRect()`, which is used in the developer tools to present the size, differs.

SVG itself has a method for measuring the bounding box of an element. In [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox), `SVGLocatable.getBBox()` excludes "stroking, clipping, masking and filter effects" and applies only to the geometry. In [SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getBBox), the interface has slightly changed. `SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox(options)` should take an `options` parameter to define whether the stroke, clip path or markers should be included. Default is to only measure the unstyled geometry. Neither Chrome nor Firefox implement this parameter.

```
document.querySelector('rect').getBBox()
> SVGRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 100}
```

`element.getBoundingClientRect()` is defined in the [CSSOM view module](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-getclientrects). To cover all cases, it is a bit more complicated, but basically it references back to `element.getClientRects()`:

> If the element has an associated SVG layout box return a DOMRectList object containing a single DOMRect object that describes the bounding box of the element as defined by the SVG specification, applying the transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors.

No reference of the `getBBox()` options parameter is made, which I understand to say it should behave like the default, without any parameter set. Chrome does that:

```
document.querySelector('rect').getBoundingClientRect() 
> DOMRect {x: 8, y: 8, width: 400, height: 100, top: 8, …}
```

But Firefox returns

```
document.querySelector('rect').getBoundingClientRect()
> DOMRect { x: 6.5, y: 6.5, width: 403, height: 103, top: 6.5, right: 409.5, bottom: 109.5, left: 6.5 }
```

including the stroke in the measurement.

While currently this is a bug in Firefox, there is a [discussion](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/339) in the SVG spec working group where at least some argue the "decorated" box would be more usefull. Currently there seems to be no urgency in resolving the difference, and the discussion is left for a future SVG 2.1 version.

Comment: We objected to the CSSOM spec definition some years ago.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. btw i think It's not a bug in firefox indeed chrome calculations are wrong! cuz even in this scenario  the real size of rect is `403 * 103` but it's kinda overflowing in svg tag and if I use correct attributes `rect` size will be `403 * 103` and chrome will calculate it as `400 * 100`. @ccprog